# What is support of source code files in Kindle?

Tags: kindle, source

I didn't have any Kindle in hand, so I might be completely wrong -- this is what I would like to do. Copy entire directory with C#, Swift, Python (and so on) files -- source code files -- so their content usually look like this:

```
parents, babies = (1, 1)
while babies < 100:
    print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
    parents, babies = (babies, parents + babies)
```

I would like to click of any of such files and see the content of the file (see above).

Does Kindle support this? Does Kindle viewer support syntax highlighting for source code files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot directly upload the files and use them. You would have to convert the file (with a syntax highlighter) to a format your kindle supports (EPUB,AZW3) and then upload those files.

I would not use PDF, I still have to come across a converter that correctly does whitespace (significant in e.g. Python) correctly. Although you might be indifferent wrt that.

Comment: Thank you very much for such complete answer. Pity Kindle is so limited...